# PyQGIS composer map add raster layer

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, print-composer, python-2.7

I try to follow this [example](https://github.com/rjspiers/qgis-standalone-map-export/blob/master/standalone_generate_pdf.py) to create a map using PyQGIS in standalone script. But in my case I don't have vector layer but I have raster layer.

Here the code :

```
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
project_path = 'single_pdf.qgs'
canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
template_path = 'single_pdf_a4_landscape.qpt'
QgsProject.instance().read(QFileInfo(project_path))
template_file = file(template_path)
template_content = template_file.read()
template_file.close()
document = QDomDocument()
document.setContent(template_content)
composition = QgsComposition(canvas.mapSettings())
substitution_map = {'title': 'hi'}
raster='raster.tif'
fileInfo = QFileInfo(raster)
path = fileInfo.filePath()
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
layer = QgsRasterLayer(path, baseName)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

composition.loadFromTemplate(document, substitution_map)
# You must set the id in the template
map_item = composition.getComposerItemById('Main Map')

layer.loadNamedStyle('NEW.qml')
map_item.setMapCanvas(canvas)
map_item.zoomToExtent(canvas.extent())

legend_item = composition.getComposerItemById('Legend')
legend_item.updateLegend()
composition.refreshItems()
composition.exportAsPDF('export.pdf')
QgsProject.instance().clear()
```

Legend work fine take legend from style, title work fine but the **Main Map** where I want to add my raster layer is empty, any idea why? Where I have the wrong in code? The problem is extent or some refresh?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Perhaps you are not giving enough time for the map to be rendered in the canvas? This was a problem for me which was solved using the [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) method. You can import it using `from time import sleep` and then before the line `composition.exportAsPDF('export.pdf')`, you can add `sleep(5)` or however long you want just so there's time for the items to be refreshed before being exported to the pdf. Five seconds works for me :)